# Deform Internationalization on Flask

Tags: python, flask, deform

The deform docs describe how to work with internationalization with the Pyramid Web Framework.
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/i18n.html

I have been banging my head to make it work with Flask, does anybody have an idea on how to do it?

I have the Flask-Babel package installed, but still, I haven't found a way to make it work with deform.

Comment: Have you checked out Flask-Babel ? http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/

Comment: Yes, I have. But I haven't found a way to make it work with deform

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs for [`Localizer.translate`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/api/i18n.html#pyramid.i18n.Localizer.translate) it looks like you would just use [`gettext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html#gettext):

```
zpt_renderer = deform.ZPTRendererFactory(
        [deform_template_dir],
        translator=lambda t, *_, **__: gettext(t))
    deform.Form.set_default_renderer(zpt_renderer)
```